# Different java versions in gradle sub-projects

Tags: gradle

I have a multi project build, and I need one project to use Java 8 when the rest use Java 6 (I know but at the moment I am unable to upgrade them all)

Is there any way to have a different version of Java for one sub-project in a multi-project build?

Thanks

Comment: Are the projects completely independent of each other?

Comment: They are separate services from a big project, but we want a single build for all services

Comment: Forking the JVM for the java compile task seems to be a valid solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349011/gradle-using-2-different-jdk

Answer (score 7):

Gradle 6.7 introduced [toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) support. Though this was primarily defined to allow specifying the Java version a project is *compiled* with independent of the Java version a Gradle build is *executed* with, it can be used to specify different Java versions for different sub projects of a multi-module project.

For instance, given two sub projects *a* and *b*, if we want to specify that *a* should compile with Java 11 and *b* with Java 17, your builds scripts would contain the following:

**project a** `build.gradle`

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}
```

**project b** `build.gradle`

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}
```